# Firebase Realtime database, how to notify there is no data in a reference

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, code-cleanup

I am trying to implement a clean way of notifying my UI that there is no data. It's more like a listener that check that there is network connection but no data at that location. How do I do this?
I have tried 998 ways :(, they all work but the complexity of implementing them in every class that listens for data is giving me nausea.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for the `snapshot` object whether there is data at that particular reference node or not like this:

```
anyRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(snapshot -> {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        // data exists
    } else { 
        // data doesn't exist 
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean.
You saved a soul.

Comment: The `snapshot` will never be `null`. Instead you'll want to check if the snapshot exists with `if (snapshot.exists) {`